# Creating a User using the ASP .NET Web Site Administration Tool. Silverlight Business Application

Tags: security, silverlight-5.0

Something is missing with my ASP .NET Web Site Administration Tool, I don't see the "Security Question" nor the "Security Answer".

According to "Walkthrough: Using Authentication Service with Silverlight Business Application" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449(v=vs.91).aspx), this is what I should see when creating a new user:

[image]

But this is what I see instead:

[image: image 2]

The "Security Question" and the "Security Answer" are missing. What could I have not installed?, I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested you have to make Custom Membership Provider Setting, like:

```
    <membership
        defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
        userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider"
                 type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                 connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                 enablePasswordReset="true"
                 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                 requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 passwordFormat="Hashed"
                 minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                 applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

in the web.config file. Notice the requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" setting.